# Qtoolbar toggle show hide on Qmenu

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, qtoolbar

How to add slot to toggle show and hide the toolbar in qmenu? This my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setMinimumSize(800, 600);

    CreateAct();
    CreateMenus();
    createToolBars();
}

void MainWindow::CreateAct()
{
    undoAct = new QAction(QIcon::fromTheme("edit-undo", QIcon(":/images/undo.png")), tr("&Undo"), this);
    redoAct = new QAction(QIcon::fromTheme("edit-redo", QIcon(":/images/redo.png")), tr("&Redo"), this);
    cutAct = new QAction(QIcon::fromTheme("edit-cut", QIcon(":/images/cut.png")), tr("Cu&t"), this);
    copyAct = new QAction(QIcon::fromTheme("edit-copy", QIcon(":/images/copy.png")), tr("&Copy"), this);
    pasteAct = new QAction(QIcon::fromTheme("edit-paste", QIcon(":/images/paste.png")), tr("&Paste"), this);

    editToolBarAct = new QAction(tr("Show edit toolbar"), this);
    editToolBarAct->setCheckable(true);
    editToolBarAct->setChecked(true);
//    connect(editToolBarAct, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), editToolBar, SLOT());

    fileToolBarAct = new QAction(tr("Show file toolbar"), this);
    fileToolBarAct->setCheckable(true);
    fileToolBarAct->setChecked(true);
//    connect(fileToolBarAct, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), fileToolBar, SLOT());
}

void MainWindow::CreateMenus()
{
    windowMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Window"));
    windowMenu->addAction(fileToolBarAct);
    windowMenu->addAction(editToolBarAct);
}

void MainWindow::createToolBars()
{
    fileToolBar = addToolBar("file");
    fileToolBar->addAction(undoAct);
    fileToolBar->addAction(redoAct);
    fileToolBar->toggleViewAction();
    fileToolBar->setAllowedAreas(Qt::TopToolBarArea | Qt::LeftToolBarArea);

    editToolBar = addToolBar(tr("Edit"));
    editToolBar->addAction(cutAct);
    editToolBar->addAction(copyAct);
    editToolBar->addAction(pasteAct);
    editToolBar->setAllowedAreas(Qt::TopToolBarArea | Qt::LeftToolBarArea);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}
```

I am know using [toggleViewAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#toggleViewAction), but how to use that code (I am really new in qt programming), can you give me sample code? I've tried googling, but did not find examples of its use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following small example demonstrates how to use the `QToolBar::toggleViewAction()`:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow()
    {
        // Create a tool bar
        QToolBar *tb = addToolBar("My Tool Bar");
        [..]

        // Create a menu and add toggle action for the tool bar.
        QAction *tba = tb->toggleViewAction();
        QMenu *m = menuBar()->addMenu("&Window");
        m->addAction(tba);
    }
};
```